# b-tree fullness (as percentage)

Tags: java, tree, b-tree, multiway-tree

I am currently busy implementing a [**B-Tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) in JAVA. One of the methods requires me return as a percentage the fullness of the complete tree. The percentage should be out of 100 and if, for example, 50 is returned, it means that the tree is 50% full. A empty tree is 0% full.

Here is the node class I am working with

```
class btNode<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
{
    boolean leaf = true;
    int keyCount = 0;
    int referenceCount= 0;
    Comparable<T>[] keys = new Comparable[m-1];
    btNode<T>[] references= new btNode[m];
    btNode(int m){...}
    ...
}
```

### To summaries: please help me implement the following method:

```
public int fullness()
{
    ???
}
```

**Any suggestions, help and/or code would be appreciated.**

Comment: Do you want your answer in Java or C++, as they are two different languages?

Comment: BTW, `Comparable<T>[]` is invalid syntax for C++.

Comment: I recommend having two separate classes for a B-Tree, the base structure and a node class.  This allows you not to duplicate fields such as `keyCount` and `referenceCount`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am implementing this in JAVA. And I know that this is not c++ code but I understand c/c++ and wont mind answers in those languages, thats why I added the c++ tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your b-tree class, maintain the number of elements in the tree and the capacity of the tree.

The percentage is "elements in tree" / capacity.

Comment: Thanks, cant believe I didn't think of this.